# How do I organise query output in the desired way?

Tags: ms-access

I want a query that outputs

```
IDNum___FName___LName____TotCharge
1_______Joe_______Pesci_____$3262
2_______Lara______Croft______$2654
etc
```

`IDNum`, `FName` and `LName` are part of Table **Physician**

TotCharge is made up of 2 sql blocks which both output in the following format

```
PhysID__Charge

1_______2034
2_______1254
etc
```

This is the code:

```
SELECT Patient.Phys_id AS Expr1, Sum(Patient.Charge) AS sum_of_Charge1
FROM Patient
GROUP BY Patient.Phys_id;
```

The only difference between the 2 is Table Patient becomes Table Treatment.

How can I get these 2 charges summed into 1 and organised into the format I want from the top of the question?

Comment: I have been able to create 2 queries that give half the required information each. SELECT Patient.Phys_id AS Expr1, Physician.FName, Physician.LName, Sum(Patient.Charge) AS sum_of_Charge1
FROM Physician INNER JOIN Patient ON Physician.Phys_ID = Patient.Phys_id
GROUP BY Patient.Phys_id, Physician.FName, Physician.LName;
gives a table with Phys_ID, FName, LName and Charge 2 Charge totals, 1 in each table (TotVisitCharge and TotTreatCharge)

Comment: Formatted tables and code.

Comment: Add (by using [edit]) your code to the question itself.

Comment: i would start with two separate queries, one for physician and a separate one for the charges (with each charge totaling on 1 row). when those are working, i would put the charges-query inside the physician query and join them on the common field, presumably PhysID. that will hopefully simplify/clarify things.